# WooCommerce HTML after short description if product is in specific category

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to show HTML text after the short description on the product page, but only on specific products that are in a specific category (categories).

I think I have to use in_category, but I can't figure out how to display the text right after the short description.

My preference is to work with a function/filter/action.

This code works:

```
function filter_woocommerce_short_description( $post_excerpt )   {
$your_msg='Test';
return $post_excerpt.'<br>'.$your_msg; 
};
add_filter( 'woocommerce_short_description','filter_woocommerce_short_description',10, 1 );
```

But this one works on all product pages..

Comment: Hello,please you can check that product category is exists or not and also count the number of category and base on that you have to add HTML text.

Comment: Can you give me an example code? I was not clear about the categories. The HTML has to be  added when the product is in one of these 2 categories, so not in both.

Comment: sorry i'm too late i'm happy to see that someone answered you so problems are resolved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Woocommerce's product categories are custom taxonomy terms, so you need to use the taxonomy functions (eg, [`has_term()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/has_term)) rather than WordPress' category ones.

```
function filter_woocommerce_short_description( $post_excerpt ) {
    global $post;
    if ( has_term( "term-name", "product_cat", $post->ID ) ) {
        $post_excerpt .= "<br/>" . "Test";
    }
    return $post_excerpt; 
};
add_filter( 'woocommerce_short_description','filter_woocommerce_short_description',10, 1 );
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. Looks like you are pointing me to the right direction. When I add this code to functions.php, the website goes blank. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, there was a missing closing `)` on the if statement. I've updated the answer. Don't forget to change `term-name` to be the one that you're testing for!

Comment: One more question: I want to add a link in the custom HTML (where Test is in your code). When I add a link, page goes blank again. Do you know why?

Comment: You would need to share your code to be able to help with that!

Comment: I added the code below

Comment: Thanks! Was looking for this!

Answer (score 0):

```
function filter_woocommerce_short_description( $post_excerpt ) {
global $post;
if ( has_term( "axtschlag", "product_cat", $post->ID ) || has_term( "grate-goods", "product_cat", $post->ID ) ) {
    $post_excerpt .= "<br/>" . "<strong>Pick 'n Mix actie!</strong><br> Kies & mix de merken <a href="/axtschlag">Axtschlag</a> en Grate Goods en ontvang korting! Kies je 3 tot 5 producten dan ontvang je 5% korting, kies je 6 tot 10 producten dan ontvang je maar liefst 10% korting direct in je winkelwagen. Geldt ook i.c.m. met lopende acties.";
}
return $post_excerpt; 
};
add_filter( 'woocommerce_short_description','filter_woocommerce_short_description',10, 1 );
```

Comment: It's because you are enclosing your string in `"` but it has also got `"` quotes in it in the `<a href="/axtschlag">` part. Replace the `"` within the string with `'` instead. Also (not an error, just cleaner) you don't need to break the string, so the `"<br/>" . "<strong>` can be just `"<br/><strong>`. Finally, `has_term()` accepts an array of terms, so you can simplify that whole line down to `if ( has_term( array("axtschlag","grate-goods"), "product_cat", $post->ID ) ) {`.